# Wildcard searches

Tags: wildcard, marklogic

Our MarkLogic based web-application mostly uses [cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery) to access needed information.
We want to provide the possibility of wildcard searches against specific JSON properties.
What is the best way to do it?

Turning on one of the wildcard indexes for the whole database is not an option.
I figured out that adding a "wildcarded" parameter to the query itself may solve the problem:

```
cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("inventor", "R?th", ["wildcarded", "whitespace-sensitive"]));
```

But it may work slow due to the absence of indexes. Is there any way to create wildcard indexes only for that specific JSON property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [Path Field](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_23934) with an XPath to the `inventor` JSON field (and even for `//inventor`) and [configure the field](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_30410) to have wildcard indexes, and then use a field query: [`cts.fieldValueQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.fieldValueQuery) or [`cts.fieldWordQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.fieldWordQuery).

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help...  It is written that "The field configuration controls the behavior of the cts:field-word-query, cts:field-value-query, cts:field-range-query, cts:field-words, and cts:field-word-match APIs." and  "These added index options will not affect other queries (for example, cts:word-query, cts:element-word-query, cts:element-attribute-word-query, cts:json-property-word-query)." But I need to control the behavior of cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery. Ideally would be if I will find some setting, which will make cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("inventor", "R*")) work.

Comment: Why not use `cts.fieldValueQuery` instead of `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery`? If you aren't looking to make a database-wide index change, and can make a specific field with supporting indexes, use the field query.

Comment: Thanks, Mads! Now is clear. I just was hoping that it will not be necessary to change the query logic in our application.